# Physical feature enabled by software update?

Tags: software

I've heard a story about someone wanted to upgrade his car with seat heating. When he called the dealership he was told his car already included the heating hardware all he need is a software update to enable the feature. Nevertheless he had to bring his car to the dealership and was charged the price of the heating (several hundreds of euros, if I recall correctly).

After months of this story I was trying to find any information of such features when a hardware is already included in the car but disabled and manufacturers/dealerships charge for enabling it. Is there any public information available on this?

Note: I've heard about [Tesla enabling features with software updates](https://electrek.co/2017/08/17/tesla-autopilot-2-0-update-automatic-high-beam/), but in that case the software was not ready earlier, and they included the hardware in the hope of releasing the software for it when it is ready. What I am looking for here is deliberately disabling features to make users pay for it later.

Comment: While I have no proof for this (thus leaving only a comment), many recent Toyota cars have a touchscreen interface for radio & media, backup camera, fuel consumption display etc. Only some of them, however, have a navigator. It is definitely possible that even base models have enough hardware for the navigation, you just need to pay extra to license the navigation software with the maps. Consider this: even $100-$200 smartphones have GPS, so a $15000 - $30000 car can very well have a GPS even without navigation software installed.